# Why would an app run fine in the system environment, but not under RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to get up to speed with [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/).

I have a Rails 2 app that works fine within my system. In other words it worked before I installed RVM and it works if I "turn RVM off" with `$ rvm use system`.

Under RVM I installed the same Ruby version and patch level as my system Ruby, and then I created a gemset and installed all the gem versions that the app uses.

However, under RVM when I run `rake gems` I get this result...

```
$ rake gems
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String

Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

With `--trace`...

```
$ rake gems --trace
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
** Invoke gems (first_time)
** Invoke gems:base (first_time)
** Execute gems:base
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:277:in `=='
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:75:in `add_load_paths'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/username/project/my_app/config/environment.rb:7
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/gems.rake:17
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

---

When I try to run the app I get...

```
$ script/server 
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:34.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:322.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.

[ ... "NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex" thing repeats a bunch of times ... ]

/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:277:in `==': undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:75:in `add_load_paths'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /Users/username/project/my_app/config/environment.rb:7
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@my_app_rails_2/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Comment: I have the strong feeling that the gems you have in your system install and RVM are different, and that's causing the error. Can you check that you're using the same version of rails and rubygems under both rubies?

Comment: Rails version: check. Individual gem versions: check. System RubyGems version: 1.3.7. RVM RubyGems version: 1.8.10. Could that be it? If so, can I downgrade RubyGems under RVM?

Comment: That sounds **highly** possible, specially since the 2nd top-line from the stacktrace is from `gem_dependency.rb`. This page on RVM explains how to use a different [RubyGems](http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/) version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, RubyGems has had a very fast development pace lately and is not completely backwards compatible. Try:

```
gem install rubygems -v 1.3.7
```

You may have to clear out the gemset to reinstall rubygems...

If you're using rvm, you can change the version of RubyGems with the following command:

```
rvm rubygems 1.3.7
```

Comment: I get these warnings all over the place too.  It's really annoying.  Doesn't seem like something that's going to go away quickly.  Is it something bundler needs to fix, or the gem authors themselves?

Comment: Thanks, DGM. Actually I think it might be better to use [RVM's built-in RubyGems version management capability](http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems) which Augusto linked to above. But you're right that was the issue.

Comment: Am using rvm with 1.8.7@rails2.3.5. With rvm rubygems 1.3.7 everything works perfect. thanks